# pandas transform nunique on groupby object dealing with nan values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following `df`,

```
inv_id    cluster_id
793        2
           2
789        3
789        3
           4
           4
```

I like to `groupby` `cluster_id` and check how many unique values each group has,

```
df['same_inv_id'] = df.groupby('cluster_id')['inv_id'].transform('nunique') == 1
```

but I like to set `same_inv_id = False` when some cluster only contains empty/blank `inv_id`, and when some cluster contains one or more empty/blank `inv_id`, so the result will look like,

```
inv_id    cluster_id    same_inv_id
793        2            False 
           2            False
789        3            True
789        3            True
           4            False
           4            False
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC get the condition then `transform`+ `all`

```
s1=df.inv_id.ne('').groupby(df.cluster_id).transform('all')
s1
Out[432]: 
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4    False
5    False
Name: inv_id, dtype: bool
s2=df.groupby('cluster_id')['inv_id'].transform('nunique') == 1 
#df['same_inv_id']=s1&s2
```