# Mean value of 2 group by's if value is not unique pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have been struggling with grouping by 2 conditions (or grouping "twice"?), adding an if unique value condition, and do the mean of those groups.

I created a sample dataset so it can be better understood: A chef makes dishes, made out of ingredients, which each cost X. They can be costing differently depending on the day or the place bought or whatever, not relevant.

```
  chef_id    dish   ingr price
0       1  dish_1  ingr1     4
1       1  dish_1  ingr2     3
2       1  dish_1  ingr3     5
3       2  dish_2  ingr1     1
4       2  dish_2  ingr2     3
5       2  dish_4  ingr1     2
6       3  dish_3  ingr1     6
7       3  dish_3  ingr2     4
```

In my real dataset, there is also a date, but I don't think it's relevant. My main objective is to **group by chefs, and dishes per chef, to do an average of the cost per dish (per chef).** But all this, **ONLY if the chef has made at least 2 DIFFERENT dishes in total** (regardless the dates, that is why I don't think it's relevant). If it has done only one (even if it's several times). The ingredients are only relevant for the price, so that is why I am not using it as a condition.

So the desired output would be something like:

```
chef_id,dish,price('mean')
2,dish_2,2
2,dish_4,2
```

I've checked [counting values per group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38309729/count-unique-values-per-groups-with-pandas), [deleting rows based on a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851535/how-to-delete-rows-from-a-pandas-dataframe-based-on-a-conditional-expression) (I also found a not in, taking the list of chefs with unique dishes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27965295/dropping-rows-from-dataframe-based-on-a-not-in-condition)), and [grouping by different conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48442561/how-to-group-data-on-pandas-with-multiple-conditions)

This works for just a mean of all dishes of all chefs, which is not my objective:

```
df_chef.groupby(['chef_id', 'dish'], as_index=False).mean('price')
```

This is my trying so far, not being able to accomplish it.

```
df_uniques = df.groupby('chef_id')['dish'].unique()
new_unique = df_uniques.to_frame().reset_index()

to_del = new_unique.loc[((new_unique['dish'].apply(len)) == 1)] #if it has only 1 dish
users_list = to_del['chef_id'].tolist() #list of chefs to delete
modi_df = df208[~df208['chef_id'].isin(users_list)]
modi_df.groupby(['chef_id','dish'])['price'].mean()
modi_df
```

According to the [docs](https://www.statology.org/pandas-mean-by-group/), once I have filtered out the chefs I don't want, I should be able to group by 2 cols, and then do a mean of one other col:

```
df.groupby(['group_col1', 'group_col2'])['value_col'].mean()
```

Comment: I see that you used `unique()`, for this the `nunique()` function is quite useful :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, get the rows with chefs that make at least two different dishes.

```
at_least_two_different_dishes = df.groupby('chef_id').dish.transform('nunique') > 1
```

Then use this and `.groupby()` to get the desired result:

```
df[at_least_two_different_dishes].groupby(['chef_id', 'dish'], as_index=False).price.mean()
```

Output:

```
   chef_id    dish  price
0        2  dish_2    2.0
1        2  dish_4    2.0
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks! Did not even find nor think about that transform to a value of a grouped df! This actually led me to something that will probably help in the future, as I will be having to group and group and...etc. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54789128/pandas-transform-nunique-on-groupby-object-dealing-with-nan-values). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The following drops the data regarding chefs who have only prepared one dish:

```
dish_ct = df_chef.groupby(['chef_id'])['dish'].nunique()
chefs = dish_ct[dish_ct > 1].index
df_chef = df_chef[df_chef['chef_id'].isin(chefs)]
```

After that, you can use your the same approach as before: the line

```
print(df_chef.groupby(['chef_id', 'dish'], as_index=False).mean('price'))
```

results in

```
   chef_id    dish  price
0        2  dish_2    2.0
1        2  dish_4    2.0
```

Comment: Worked neatly and it seems I was not that far, thanks a lot!